# Any Microformats for Video

Tags: html, video, microformats

Has anyone created HTML microformats for video and video overlays including:

- Video File
- Links with timecode (start/end) and screen region

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found that best suites my needs:  [Apple's Final Cut Pro XML Format](http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/AppleApplications/idxFinalCutProFinalCutExpress-date.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few [examples](http://microformats.org/wiki/video-info-examples) at the MF wiki - do they help at all?

Comment: Ross,
The formats that are listed there tell about the video as a whole, not about the running data - I want to add links to specific times and regions within the video itself.  I am looking for a video tagging microformat.